# iPhone SDK : How to localize a Class?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to localize a class (.h & .m files) in my application. I made the same operation as when I localized my interface (xib -> Get info -> make file localizable). I created a second .h and a second .m file, and I made the modifications I needed for the new location. Great !

But it just doesn't work...

I get the error:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_

Does anyone have a clue ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you already tried to use "clean up" in xcode? Sometimes old object data causes this duplicate symbol error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are just on the wrong path..
For localization you need not create separate .m & .h files.Only Xibs are to be created.
Other than that you have to create separate Localizable.strings file for each localization.
For more understanding just chk out this link http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/a-simple-localization-example-for-the-iphone

It contains the link for downloading the sample code also.